# Stacked Graph - AmChart - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts, area, stacked

I've created an AmChart which is supposed to show stacked aeras.
I don't know why, everything goes fine except the graphs aren't stacked...

Here's the code:

```js
 var JSONChart = {
        "type":"serial",
        "backgroundAlpha":1,
        "backgroundColor":"white",
        "autoMargin":true,"autoMarginOffset":30,
        "marginRight":50,
        "creditsPosition":"bottom-right",
        "titles":"TEST",
        "fontSize":15,
        "categoryAxis": {"parseDates":true,"minPeriod":"ss","axisAlpha":1,"gridAlpha":"white",},
        "chartScrollbar":{"enabled":true,"backgroundAlpha":1},
        "dataProvider":Tableau,
        "categoryField":"Date",
        "ValueAxis":[{"stackType":"regular","axisAlpha":0,"gridAlpha":0.1,"unit":"MWh","unitPosition":"left"}],
        "chartCursor":{"cursorColor":"red","valueLineBalloonEnabled":true,"valueLineEnabled":true,"valueZoomable":true},
        }

        var Graphiques =  [];
        for (var j=1;j<TableFinale[0].length;j++){
            var Param = {};
            Param.id = "g"+j.toString();
            Param.type = "line";
            Param.lineColor = "red";
            Param.valueField = j.toString();
            Param.fillAlphas = 0.3;
            Graphiques.push(Param);
        }
        JSONChart.graphs=Graphiques;

        customVisualzationObject = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",JSONChart );
```

do you have an idea why the "regular" value of the Stacktype property doesn't apply?

Thanks

---

I changed the spelling, here's the code now:

```
    evar JSONChart = {
        "type":"serial",
        "ValueAxes": [{"stackType":"regular","axisAlpha":0,"gridAlpha":0.1,"unit":"MWh","unitPosition":"left"}],
        "backgroundAlpha":1,
        "backgroundColor":"white",
        "autoMargin":true,"autoMarginOffset":30,
        "marginRight":50,
        "creditsPosition":"bottom-right",
        "titles":"TEST",
        "fontSize":15,
        "categoryAxis": {"parseDates":true,"minPeriod":"mm","axisAlpha":1,"gridAlpha":"white"},
        "chartScrollbar":{"enabled":true,"backgroundAlpha":1},
        "dataProvider":Tableau,
        "categoryField":"Date",
        "chartCursor":{"cursorColor":"blue","valueLineBalloonEnabled":true,"valueLineEnabled":true,"valueZoomable":true},
        "Legend":{"position":"top","valueTextRegular":"bite","valueWidth":100},
        "export": {
        "enabled": true, "position":"bottom-right" }
        }

        var Graphiques =  [];
        for (var j=1;j<TableFinale[0].length;j++){
            var Param = {};
            Param.id = "g"+j.toString();
            Param.type = "line";
            Param.lineColor = getRandomColor();
            Param.valueField = j.toString();
            Param.fillAlphas = 0.3;
            Graphiques.push(Param);
        }
        JSONChart.graphs=Graphiques;
```

The final chart is still not stacked... I don't know why.
The legend is not working too though.

Here's is the dataprovider table I'm using:
[image]

I really don't understand what's wrong in my JSON.
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due the misspelled variable name:

- In your JSONChart object try to change the attribute name from "ValueAx**i**s" to "ValueAx**e**s" instead.

Ref:

- [Unable add ValueAxis property to Amchart stock graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668623/unable-add-valueaxis-property-to-amchart-stock-graph)
- [amCharts valueAxis maximum not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075659/amcharts-valueaxis-maximum-not-working)
- https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/time-line-chart-date-based-milestones/

Comment: I tried with "ValueAxes" but it's the same...
In documentation i've found both spelling : ValueAxis, ValueAxes...

Comment: You want `valueAxes` in the chart JSON config (lowercase v). For non-gantt charts, you're creating an array of value axis objects, so the property is called `valueAxes` ([documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#valueAxes)). `valueAxis` is for a gantt chart as it only contains one value axis. `legend` also needs to be lowercase.